# How to create many properties at the same time using list/arrays

Tags: python, scripting

I want to create some integer properties using loops just to save time and lines of code. So basically, the new properties should be something like this:

```
bpy.types.Scene.prop1
bpy.types.Scene.prop2
bpy.types.Scene.prop3
....
....
bpy.types.Scene.prop10
```

Here is my approach. First, I created a list of desired variables, "prop1...prop10".

```
prop_name = ["prop%d"%(i+1) for i in range(10)]
```

Then I use a for loop to create these properties.

```
for i, name in enumerate(prop_name):
    bpy.types.Scene.name = bpy.props.IntProperty(name="prop %d"%(i+1))
```

With this, I expect 10 properties. Now I have 2 issue:

The name that should be shown inside the properties is not changing with respect to their index values.

2nd Issue: I'm not actually able to put them in my Panel. So, I guess, there are no properties created with this method.

```
(<built-in function Intproperty>, {'name':'prop10','attr':'name'})
(<built-in function Intproperty>, {'name':'prop10','attr':'name'})
(<built-in function Intproperty>, {'name':'prop10','attr':'name'})
(<built-in function Intproperty>, {'name':'prop10','attr':'name'})
```

How can I change this name with index value, or let me know if there is an another way to create multiple properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the python built in method [setattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr)

> The function assigns the value to the attribute, provided the object allows it. For example, `setattr(x, 'foobar', 123)` is equivalent to `x.foobar = 123`.

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import IntProperty
from bpy.types import Scene

prop_name = ["prop%d" % (i+1) for i in range(10)]

for i, name in enumerate(prop_name):
    setattr(Scene, name, IntProperty(name="prop %d" % (i+1)))
```

On your code, you are setting the name property of `Scene` class ten times to an `IntProperty`.

```
for i, name in enumerate(prop_name):
    bpy.types.Scene.name = bpy.props.IntProperty(name="prop %d"%(i+1))
```

is equivalent to

```
bpy.types.Scene.name = IntProperty(name="prop 1")
bpy.types.Scene.name = IntProperty(name="prop 2")
...
bpy.types.Scene.name = IntProperty(name="prop 10")
```

This is a double whammy, as `Scene` already has a `StringProperty` [name](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.ID.html#bpy.types.ID.name).  (eg `bpy.data.scenes["NAME"]` has "NAME" for a name)  [The ID class is a base class for all blender objects in the subclass list](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.ID.html#module-bpy.types). Another clue this is ***BAD*** is the blank scene name in UI after running question code.  Click on scene name and it will most likely crash blender.

Comment: That works for me but then I stuck again at some time. How do I make the following shorten: bcs = bpy.context.scene and the a variable called props contain all these class objects in a list [bcs.prop1, bcs.prop2, bcs.prop3, bcs.prop4, bcs.prop5, bcs.prop6, bcs.prop7, bcs.prop8, bcs.prop9, bcs.prop10]

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr

Comment: It seems to be a bit complicated to understand this method when one need to use it other way around. Now I understand how to create properties and register it. But now how do I un-register these properties, like del bpy.types.Scene.prop1 in a loop.

Comment: Perhaps you could edit your question, or ask a new question, with all these new requests.  AFAIC my answer covers the Q.    Surely after seeing `setattr` in use , [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr), eg ( `[getattr(obj, p) for p in props]` ) is not too complicated?